# Android gson serialization issue

Tags: android, http-post, gson

I have HttpPost request on my Android application to my .NET Web Api.

I am using json data type and [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) class in order to serialize my object.

Here is my code about serialization:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
    post.setURI(new URI("my url goes here"));
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("username", username);
    hashMap.put("userCredentials", new Gson().toJson(credentials, UCredentials.class));
    // username and credentials are parameters.
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(hashMap)));

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // If successful.
    }
```

Except `hashMap.put("userCredentials", new Gson().toJson(credentials, UCredentials.class));` code line everything works fine. But with this line...

Gson class gives me json as:

```
{
    "userCredentials":
        "{
            \"emailOrUsername\":\"asd@sadas.com\",
            \"password\":\"113\"
         }",
    "username":"sdggfsdgf"
}
```

and it is not valid json pattern. I need json output like:

```
{
        "userCredentials":
            {
                "emailOrUsername":"asd@sadas.com",
                "password":"113"
            },
        "username":"sdggfsdgf"
}
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue is here:

```
 hashMap.put("userCredentials", new Gson().toJson(credentials, UCredentials.class));
```

What is going into the HashMap is a String that is JSON parsable. When you follow that up with:

```
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(hashMap)));
```

That string gets escaped since it is not an object.

What you really want to do is something like this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost();

post.setURI(new URI("my url goes here"));
// Here we say that the Hashmap takes Object as its value.
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hashMap.put("username", username);
// Here we put the credentials object in the HashMap
hashMap.put("userCredentials", credentials);
// username and credentials are parameters.
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
Type mapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(hashMap, mapType)));

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    // If successful.
}
```

This should do what you want, but since you say it doesn't work....

I'm not sure about the UCredentials class. It appears to be your own code. Here's a guess on my part:

```
public class UCredentials {

    public String emailOrUsername;

    public String password;

}
```

Here is simplified code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.google.gson.Gson;    
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        UCredentials uc = new UCredentials();
        uc.emailOrUsername = "me@somehost.com";
        uc.password = "pAsSwOrD";

        hashMap.put("username", "ME");
        hashMap.put("userCredentials", uc);

        Type mapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(hashMap, mapType));
    }

}
```

And this is the output:

> {"userCredentials":{"emailOrUsername":"me@somehost.com","password":"pAsSwOrD"},"username":"ME"}

If you can post your error message, I'll try and help debug.

Comment: Firstly, it must be "HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();" not "HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();"

Comment: And code does not work. hashMap.put("userCredentials", credentials); line did nothing about serialization.

Comment: Try reading the documentation on generics. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Comment: I've added the TypeToken declaration.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer. I had tried this before. And I tried for the last time on my onCreate() method. It worked. The problem is that I am C# developer, I had confused between C# and Java programming. I had some incorrect definitions. Sorry for confusion. Thanks a lot for answer.

Answer (score 0):

If do you using gson to serilizable your object, you need using the URLEncoder.encode(yourClass, "UTF-8");

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String objectSerializable;

  objectSerializable= gson.toJson(yourObject, yourClass.class).toString();

  pedidoSerializado = URLEncoder.encode(objectSerializable, "UTF-8");
  String urlPathService = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/RestfulAPI/api?object="+objectSerializable;
```

Sorry for my english.